# how to use an item from a dictionary in a function and then loop the function until it goes through the whole dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input").send_keys(acountstodm)

The acountstodm is a dictionary with a bunch of accounts that I need my program to run through. I cant type them all in at the same time or else it would send it in a big group and I need to send each thing individually. I have a function that runs this line of code and a bunch of other lines which looks like this - def dm():  I need this code to run until all the accounts in the dictionary have been run through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for key, value in acountstodm.items()
```

this is how you access each key and value individually. Just put your function inside the loop